# No menu link is working after the website is deployed on hosting server

Tags: migrations

I developed a website in the drupal and I have been accessing it in the development environment using the url like this "http://localhost/foldername"...

Now I have deployed the website (the folder "foldername" and database) to my Linux based hosting server.

I have to access it for testing using a URL like this "http://HostingServerIpAddress/~HostingServerUserName/foldername".

To my surprise, no menu link is working over there :( the paths are correct. The menu links which were opening in my local environment, are giving 404 error when opened using hosting urls... :(

Please guide me at your earliest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I move a site to the production environment and can only access it using an URL as you describe, I have to disable Drupal's 'Clean URLs' functionality (`admin/config/search/clean-urls`) in order for menu links to work properly (and probably clear the caches afterwards).

**Edit:**

In the [documentation on configuring clean URLs](https://www.drupal.org/node/15365), I found that changing the RewriteBase setting in the .htaccess file is the solution for me to have clean URLs once again.

So, in your case it probably should be: `RewriteBase /~HostingServerUserName/foldername`

Comment: Thanx for your reply... I am even unable to login, because it is also a link e.g. ("http://HostingServerIpAddress/~HostingServerUserName/foldername/user")

So I can't do any of the change you suggested :(

Comment: I used the suffix ?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls
in my URLs and it worked :)

Comment: I can't vote your reply Up, I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Now I want to re-enable the Clean URLs, but my web site is not showing me the checkbox for enabling it. It shows a button for Run Clean URls Test and the test is failing... :(

Comment: @khurram, I've edited the answer. For me, changing the RewriteBase in the .htaccess file allows the clean URLs to work properly again. If this doesn't work for you, multiple solutions are given in the linked document, so give it a try :)

Comment: the change that you suggested in .htaccess file is not working :(
This is what I did, I edit the file .htaccess present in the my foldername and added the line in it 
"RewriteBase /~HostingServerUserName/foldername"

But it is not working...

Comment: Did you also try to set the $base_url variable in settings.php?

Comment: No to $base_url

Tell me, do I have to restart apache server after making that change?

Comment: I don't think restarting apache will have any effect, however, I'm not a sysadmin.. For me, the RewriteBase setting solved the problem. The documentation (https://www.drupal.org/node/15365) should contain all necessary information to solve your problem. I also recommend to check out the comments/documentation in the .htaccess en settings.php file.